# Arduino speaker using sd card code error

Tags: arduino-uno

I have basically connected a speaker to Arduino uno board. I just need help with the code. I have used the TMRpcm library to make it easier. However, it seems to be giving me an error everytime. here is the code below.

```
include "SD.h"
define SD_ChipSelectPin 10
include "TMRpcm.h"
include "SPI.h"

TMRpcm audio;

void setup(){
audio.speakerPin = 9;
Serial.begin(9600);
if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) {
Serial.println("SD fail");
return;
}

audio.setVolume(10);
audio.play("Spring_In_My_Step_-_Silent_Partner_Mp3Converter_ne.wav");
}

void loop()
{ 

}
```

any and all help is appreciated
thank you!

Comment: P.S. this is the error code i get: C:\Users\ritik\Desktop\EVERYTHING\Arduino\sketch_jan22a\sketch_jan22a.ino: In function 'void setup()':

C:\Users\ritik\Desktop\EVERYTHING\Arduino\sketch_jan22a\sketch_jan22a.ino:17:68: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

 audio.play("Spring_In_My_Step_-_Silent_Partner_Mp3Converter_ne.wav");

Comment: I've never tried that audio library, but I think that error means that audio.play() wants a String instead of a literal.
Try this:
    audio.play(String("Spring_In_My_Step_-_Silent_Partner_Mp3Converter_ne.wav"));